# Huge size of .objs normal?

Tags: modeling, file-format

I had modelled two dolls in Maya and as I work now in Blender I passed the maya doll parts to objs, and this objs opened in Blender. Worked with them, and in order to be printed, sent again in .obj files.
What I am finding now is that each little doll piece extracted as .obj weights the monstruous size of 992 Mg for example (a little piece only).

I´m sure there is a problem. If the original Maya file weighted 16Mb, and the one passed on to Blender weights 7Mb, how can it be that one small piece inside this file weights 992 Mb??

Do you happen to have come across whith some problem related to transfering files from Maya to Bleder or something related the .obj tipe of file?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You probably had generative modifiers like subdivision and mirror in the original objects that got applied as real geometry on export, increasing size of data do store. Pure speculation thought, as it is impossible to tell without more info. Please edit your question and provide more details about your model like screenshots and topology

Comment: thanks a lot! you´re right! I applied subdivision modifier but didn´t convert the piece to its final smoothed state. I think that´s the problem. Thanks a lot for your guide :)